# Taxonomy view problems

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have a taxonomy list (sector), linked with differtent content, for example:

Company 1 has taxonomy Security & Computers.
Company 2 has taxonomy Security
Company 3 has taxonomy Computers

I created a view, but, in my view I get the following result:

Security
Company 2

SecurityComputers
Company 1

Computers
Company 3

Is it possible to get:

Security
**Company 1**
Company 2

Computers
**Company 1**
Company 3

So, that he show 2 times the company who is linked with different taxonomy?...

Answer (score 0):

You should group your view by Taxonomy and for the taxonomy field in the view you should uncheck "Display all values in the same row".

These are the steps:

Add a taxonomy field to your view and uncheck "Display all values in the same row" and exclude this field from display.

Use the taxonomy field to group your view (Format settings of the view)

Of course add title field or other field to your view to have your content displayed (e. g. Company 1, 2, 3).